# Equation of a tangent line for circles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, circles

When calculating a tangent to a circle, is the method the same as tangent to a curve?

Problem: A circle has a radius of $2$ and is centered at the origin. Find the the equation of the tangent line to the circle at $(1, \sqrt{3})$.

From here, would I just isolate $y$ and use implicit differentiation, and then plug $1$ into that - or is the correct method different from that?

Comment: Use $f(x) = \sqrt{4-x^2}$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The method you described is correct.  Alternatively, you can solve the equation of the circle for $y$, taking the appropriate sign (positive, in this case, since $(1, \sqrt{3})$ is in the upper semi-circle), then finding the derivative at the point of tangency to obtain the slope of the tangent line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a needless calculus approach. We know that the tangent line is perpendicular to the radius. You just need a vector so that

$[a,b]\cdot [1,\sqrt{3}]=0$. In other words, $[\sqrt{3},-1]$ will suffice. So the line is just parametrized by: $(1,\sqrt{3})+t[\sqrt{3},-1]$.

the slope is also clear this way: $\frac{-1}{\sqrt{3}}$...

If you haven't seen vectors, this is equivalent to taking the so-called "negative reciprocal"

If you insist on a calculus approach, at least use polar co-ordinates so you don't have to take an annoying derivative.

Comment: You can type \sqrt{x} in math mode to obtain $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: point taken, edited.

Answer (score 1):

a=2;
Differentiate $ \sqrt{a^2-x^2} $

or implicitly find slope from

$$ 2 x + 2 y \frac{dy}{dx} =0  $$

and then use straight line (point, slope) form for tangent.

Same for any curve incl.  circle.